# Is 7-nitroindazole neuroprotective against meth because it oxidizes peroxynitrate?

Tags: pharmacology, neurology

So 7-nitroindazole (7-NI) [prevents methamphetamine (METH) induced neurotoxicity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8858965) AND completely [prevents meth induced dopamine depletion](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8858965), but [doesn't prevent meth induced hyperthermia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11006970). Strangely, a different study said that [its possibly because of 7-NID's ability to prevent hyperthermia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9760103), (however it is important to note that this study did not test body temperature), yet all the other studies say the opposite, that 7-NI doesn't prevent meth induced hyperthermia.

Keep in mind that [colder enviromental tempratures](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12706754) significantly attenuated METH-induced neurotoxicity

Could the reason as to why 7-NI prevents METH induced neurotoxicity and dopamine depletion simply be because it oxidizes dopamine oxidizer peroxynitrite noting that non-meth induced hyperthermia also cause neurotoxicity and produces peroxynitrite while showing the same neurotoxicity markers as METH induced neurotoxicity such as nitrotyrosine?